# How to make Outer part of the box to be clickable?

Tags: flutter, dart

Please help me with this. I am new to flutter

[image: Visual Example]

The **amber** colored container/box is clickable/hyperlink. How do I make the white part to be also clickable?

Here is the code snippet :

```
Row(children: [
Expanded(
      flex: 3,
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: onTap,
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.amber,
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
              top: 15,
              bottom: 15,
            ),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text(
                  label ?? '',
                  maxLines: 1,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  style: StyleKit.getWordStyle(
                    'b2bk',
                    color: labelColor,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );])
```

Comment: you can wrap with another clickable widget like GuestureDetector

Comment: I did but it didnt do anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is that I stack a container on top of the widget :

```
Stack (
  children : [
              Row(children: [
               Expanded(...))
              Position( 
                //adjust suitable position here
                child : Container ( same size as the yellow box))
              ]
)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can give fix height to the buttons in `Row` and wrap in an Clickable widget like below.

```
  InkWell(
      onTap: () => debugPrint("White area tapped"),
      child: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: 120,
        color: Colors.purple.shade300,
        child: Row(....),
      ),
    )
```

By doing this your outer area will also get clickable.